# Replace with a custom function with Python re

Tags: python, regex, python-re

For a string

```
s = '{{a,b}} and {{c,d}} and {{0,2}}'
```

I'd like to replace every `{{...}}` pattern by randomly one of the items in the list inside, i.e.:

```
"a and d and 2"  
"b and d and 0"  
"b and c and 0"
...
```

I remember that there's a way in module `re` to not simply replace like `re.sub`, but have a custom replacement function, but I can't find this anymore in the doc (maybe I'm searching with wrong keywords...)

This doesn't give any output:

```
import re

r = re.match('{{.*?}}', '{{a,b}} and {{c,d}} and {{0,2}}')
for m in r.groups():
    print(m)
```

Comment: The [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) docs have an example of using a function for `repl`.  Also be aware that `{}` have special meaning within regex and will need to be escaped if you want a literal match.

Comment: @0x5453 No, `{{.*?}}` is a valid pattern. No need to escape anything. It is not Android or C++ (MSVC).

Comment: You may consider ` re.sub(r'{{(\w+),(\w+)}}', lambda x: x.group(random.choice([1,2])), s)`, but it will support just two values. Do you want to produce a single result, or all possible permutations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
import random, re

def replace(match):
    lst = match.group(1).split(",")
    return random.choice(lst)

s = '{{a,b}} and {{c,d}} and {{0,2}}'

s = re.sub(r"{{([^{}]+)}}", replace, s)
print(s)
```

Or - if you're into one-liners (not advisable though):

```
s = re.sub(
    r"{{([^{}]+)}}", 
    lambda x: random.choice(x.group(1).split(",")), 
    s)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid splitting using appropriate regex to fetch patterns:

```
import re, random

s = '{{a,b}} and {{c,d}} and {{0,2}}'
s = re.sub(r'{{(.*?),(.*?)}}', random.choice(['\\1', '\\2']), s)

# a and c and 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd like the custom replacement function to work for any length of the list (here only 2 items), do you have any idea?

Comment: @Basj, Splitting is the option for any length list. But for small lengths, you can see using the approach in my answer.